# Are questions about balancing mechanics on topic?

Tags: discussion

This question about [balancing a momentum mechanic](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/133697/balancing-a-momentum-mechanic-board-game) was referred over to GDSE. Is it not on topic here? Why or why not?

Comment: I'm curious as to where the asker of that question was told to go to GeamDev.SE. They have never asked a question here (unless one was deleted), and I don't remember anyone in chat saying something like that.

Answer (score 3):

That question looks fine for this site. We do accept board game design questions (see the [game-design](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-design) tag), and that looks like a decent one. I'm pretty sure we'd accept a migration of that question to this site.