# Asked a Yes/No question on mechanics, but Closed for Opinion Based?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, closed-questions

[This](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/49416/would-a-common-token-house-rule-speed-up-monopoly-without-impacting-balance) was my question on utilizing a common token change to a commonly played board game (which has recently been voted into deletion):

[image: Picture of "Would a common token House rule speed up Monopoly without impacting balance?"]

[image: Bottom half of the question, with suggested changes and voter's names ommited for simplicity/privacy]

---

However, a [Meta question on the topic of "Are Questions on Balancing Mechanics  On-Topic"](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1538/29907) (that is in reference to [a much more open-ended mechanics question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/33201/balancing-a-momentum-mechanic), which included the query of "is this mechanic too 'weird'") was answered by a moderator with a positive "Yes".

Perhaps I'm new, and there's something I'm missing, but the example question seems to be much more opinion-based than my own.

Could someone help me understand why?  I'd like to make sure I don't repeat this mistake in the future, but I'm not seeing enough of a pattern to learn from this.

Answer (score 4):

I disagree that this is a simple yes/no question as it seem pretty clear that it does have a big impact on the balance of the game with the question being what kind of impact it would have (positive/neutral/negative). Each group based on how they work together overall might rate each of the impacts differently.

In my opinion I think a better question would be to ask what the impacts from this rule would be as those are less likely to be opinion based.

Answer (score 3):

It wasn't a yes/no question at the time it was closed.

Being yes/no doesn't make a question immune to being closed as primarily opinion-based anyway. “Are these mechanics cool?” is a yes/no question. Anyway, let's dive into this case.

If you visit [the question's revision history](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/posts/49416/revisions) (accessible by hitting the "edited X time ago" link at the bottom center) you'll be able to see when it was closed:

> [image: "post closed as primarily opinion-based", listed above revision 2 and 1]

In this case we can see it was closed after revision 2. We can click the "2" to and expand to see what the revision looked like at that stage.

> [image: revision 2 expanded]

“Any pros out there able to give some advice?” being the operative question makes this a discussion question fitting our [questions to avoid asking](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) criteria. It won't attract a best/correct answer; instead it's chatty and open-ended. Every answer will be equally valid, because every answer will ostensibly contain advice. Naturally this would be closed as opinion-based.

The question has since been edited, but it will remain closed until enough people decide it's worth reopening.

(My observation: never ask for “any advice?” or “any tips?”, because we will get exactly that: an endless list of advice and tips of arbitrary quality, instead of actual solid answers. Always directly request a comprehensive answer or solution to your problem.)

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that the original "too opinion based" was related to the wording of the question as asking for advice. With the edits, the focus on mechanical conflicts makes it looks a lot more objective to me, and I think it is now an acceptable question.

I have undeleted the question. You can now vote to reopen it, which will push it into the reopen queue if it doesn't go there automatically.